# Using width / length / height as dynamic option

Tags: expresso-store

Im using  this answer 
[Recommendation for dynamic Store product data updates](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17628/recommendation-for-dynamic-store-product-data-updates) to setup my products, wich works great but the problem is they are not getting added as seperate products like products with product modifiers, basicly it only adds one quantity to the product.

Is there any way todo this? I could setup a dynamic product variable, but it would be great todo it this way.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, can you elaborate a little on the problem? What exactly are you aiming to do, how do you currently have things setup, and what do you mean by "_it only adds one quantity to the product_"?

Comment: Hi Ian,

Basicly im using the weight / length and height product attributes to calculate my product price dynamicly by javascript. But every product you add to the cart add's one up to the quanity (because it's not a modifiers) wich makes me unable to put different product into the cart.

Now i know i can use a variable text modifer to add to the product(and it get added seperatly to the cart), but this way it would be much easier for me to setup.

Answer (score 1):

That's a side effect of the fact that Store simply combines any products with the same modifiers. Unfortunately, if you don't change any modifiers, the products will become a single line item in the cart.

One solution would be to add a hidden modifier to the product, which you generate (either randomly or based on the dimensions). You can then use conditionals to hide this modifier in the checkout, so the only thing it will affect is the display of individual line items.

Comment: Yes i know, but then i have to add those product modifiers to each product. And my store has like 500 products, that's why i wanted to try this solution. But i get it, it's no problem, i will do it the other way :)