# Adding Dimensions to Products with Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store

Hello where would you think the best place to add Length x Width x Height to the products?
I would think that this would then update the shipping details with costs. Rules don't seem to facilitate this.
[Recommendation for dynamic Store product data updates](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17628/recommendation-for-dynamic-store-product-data-updates)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already in the forum thread you linked to. You would set these fields as hidden fields on the product page and you would use JavaScript to fill these values in when the user *adds to cart* (use the on click event of the button as the trigger).

To enable this, when you add the *Store Product Details* field to your channel field group you will see an option to *Enable Dynamic Weight & Dimensions*:

[image]

You need to set this to Yes so they can be submitted from the front-end.

As long as you setup your shipping rules then they will match the selected dimensions of the product and increase or decrease shipping cost accordingly.